# PHP unzip string

Tags: php, google-drive-api, unzip

I'm loading in a Google Drive spreadsheet via the API into PHP. The request returns the `XLSX` spreadsheet and I need to unzip it. To save me writing the response to a temporary and then calling, say, `zip_open()`, is there a way I can just pass such method a string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your best option is to create a temporary file and then to unzip it.

```
// Create a temporary file which creates file with unique file name
$tmp = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), md5(uniqid(microtime(true))));

// Write the zipped content inside
file_put_contents($tmp, $zippedContent);

// Uncompress and read the ZIP archive
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if (true === $zip->open($tmp)) {
    // Do whatever you want with the archive... 
    // such as $zip->extractTo($dir); $zip->close();
}

// Delete the temporary file
unlink($tmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd write temporary file myself, but you may want to see the first comment here: http://de3.php.net/manual/en/ref.zip.php

---

> wdtemp at seznam dot cz
>   Hi, if you have the RAW CONTENT
>   OF THE ZIP FILE IN A STRING ONLY and you can't create files on your
>   server (because of the SAFE MODE) to be able to create a file which
>   you can then pass to zip_open(), you'll be having hard times getting
>   the uncompressed content of your ZIP data. This may help: I've written
>   simple ZIP decompression function for decompressing the first file
>   from the archive stored in a string (no matter what file it is). It's
>   just about parsing a local file header of the first file, getting raw
>   compressed data of that file and decompression of that data (usually,
>   data in ZIP files are compressed by 'DEFLATE' method, so we'll just
>   decompress it by gzinflate() function then).

```
<?php
function decompress_first_file_from_zip($ZIPContentStr){
//Input: ZIP archive - content of entire ZIP archive as a string
//Output: decompressed content of the first file packed in the ZIP archive
    //let's parse the ZIP archive
    //(see 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29' for details)
    //parse 'local file header' for the first file entry in the ZIP archive
    if(strlen($ZIPContentStr)<102){
        //any ZIP file smaller than 102 bytes is invalid
        printf("error: input data too short<br />\n");
        return '';
    }
    $CompressedSize=binstrtonum(substr($ZIPContentStr,18,4));
    $UncompressedSize=binstrtonum(substr($ZIPContentStr,22,4));
    $FileNameLen=binstrtonum(substr($ZIPContentStr,26,2));
    $ExtraFieldLen=binstrtonum(substr($ZIPContentStr,28,2));
    $Offs=30+$FileNameLen+$ExtraFieldLen;
    $ZIPData=substr($ZIPContentStr,$Offs,$CompressedSize);
    $Data=gzinflate($ZIPData);
    if(strlen($Data)!=$UncompressedSize){
        printf("error: uncompressed data have wrong size<br />\n");
        return '';
    }
    else return $Data;
}

function binstrtonum($Str){
//Returns a number represented in a raw binary data passed as string.
//This is useful for example when reading integers from a file,
// when we have the content of the file in a string only.
//Examples:
// chr(0xFF) will result as 255
// chr(0xFF).chr(0xFF).chr(0x00).chr(0x00) will result as 65535
// chr(0xFF).chr(0xFF).chr(0xFF).chr(0x00) will result as 16777215
    $Num=0;
    for($TC1=strlen($Str)-1;$TC1>=0;$TC1--){ //go from most significant byte
        $Num<<=8; //shift to left by one byte (8 bits)
        $Num|=ord($Str[$TC1]); //add new byte
    }
    return $Num;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the zlib functions (if available on your system). As far as i know there is something like `zlib-decode` (or so), which can handle raw zip data.